# Javascript Appear() function does not run, while Hide() does

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that the Hide function runs perfectly, but the Appear one does not.
I have 2 panels: One for Sign Up and one for Register, i want that if the user clicks on the register button, then the login panel disappears and the register one appears at the same place, as login was.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```js
    function Hide() {
       var x = document.getElementById("bejelentkezes");
       if (x.display.style === "block") {
        x.display.style = "none";
       }
    }
    
    function Appear() {
     var y = document.getElementById("regisztracio");
     if (y.display.style === "none") {
      y.display.style = "block";
     }
    }
```

```html
<div id="bejelentkezes">
            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header">Bejelentkezés</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="Hide();Appear();">Regisztráció</a>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div id="regisztracio" style="display:none;">
            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header">Regisztráció</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="Hide()">Regisztráció</a>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think your javascript is fine, but you're trying to execute Hide() and Appear() in the same click. I'm assuming you want to have one button to hide the content and another one to display it again?

Comment: No, i want one button to make the login form disappear and the register form appear, but the problem is that if i look my function.js file in my browser it only has the Hide function in it.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
element.style.display=value
```

not

```
element.display.style=value
```

```js
function Hide() {
       var x = document.getElementById("bejelentkezes");
       if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
       }
    }
    
    function Appear() {
     var y = document.getElementById("regisztracio");
     if (y.style.display === "none") {
      y.style.display = "block";
     }
    }
```

```html
<div id="bejelentkezes">
            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header">Bejelentkezés</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="Hide();Appear();">Regisztráció</a>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div id="regisztracio" style="display:none;">
            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header">Regisztráció</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="Hide()">Regisztráció</a>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

[Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Comment: Tried, it still not working, i might found the problem that in the browser, my function.js only has the Hide function in it, and not the Appear function, so it doesnt load the whole js file only just one function

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve toggle functionality.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

            document.querySelectorAll('.reg').forEach(function (elem) {
                elem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var x = document.getElementById("bejelentkezes");
                    var y = document.getElementById("regisztracio");
                    if (y.style.display === "none") {
                        y.style.display = "block";
                        x.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        y.style.display = "none";
                        x.style.display = "block";
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

```html
<div id="bejelentkezes">
    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Bejelentkezés</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Email">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                <br>
                <a href="#" class="btn reg">Regisztráció</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="regisztracio" style="display:none;">
    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Regisztráció</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Email">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés</button>
                <br>
                <a href="#" class="btn reg">Regisztráció</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant get or set `y.display.style` you wanted `y.style.display`
    (display is a property of style and not the opposite).
2. based on your code, you should do it more simple and maintainable, I would use one function - `HandleView()` that will check the state of the panels and will activate `Hide()` and `Appear()`. please see my suggestion.

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=d3bbd32e-667c-46a3-a3e3-c46bb9417287)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--remove comment to use jquery-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bejelentkezes">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Bejelentkezés
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím
              </label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó
              </label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés
            </button>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="HandleView()">Regisztráció
            </a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="regisztracio" style="display:none;">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Regisztráció
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email cím
              </label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Jelszó
              </label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Jelszó">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Bejelentkezés
            </button>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="btn reg" onclick="HandleView()">Regisztráció
            </a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function Hide(elem) {
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }
    function Appear(elem) {
      elem.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HandleView()
    {
      var y = document.getElementById("regisztracio");
      var x = document.getElementById("bejelentkezes");
      if (y.style.display === "none") {
        Appear(y);
        Hide(x);
      }
      else
      {
        Appear(x);
        Hide(y);
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```